# Could not load Connect session adapter :: connect-mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, sails.js, mongodb-atlas

I keep getting this error and my Sails (v0.12) won't start. I triend everything and to be honest I do not really undertand the message itself. Can some lease give me guidence. I'm using MongoDB Atlas. I've chachged the string, change the dependencies version, etc. Nothin seems to work.

```
node:11676) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
[0] (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
[0] error: A hook (`session`) failed to load!
[0] error: Could not load Connect session adapter :: connect-mongo
[0] 
[0] Error from adapter:
[0] Error: invalid schema, expected mongodb
[0]     at module.exports (/Users/biggahd/Desktop/Mars-EMS-v-1.0.0/root/backend/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/url_parser.js:20:11)
[0]     at connect (/Users/biggahd/Desktop/Mars-EMS-v-1.0.0/root/backend/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:125:16)
[0]     at Function.MongoClient.connect (/Users/biggahd/Desktop/Mars-EMS-v-1.0.0/root/backend/node_modules/connect-mongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:109:3)
[0]     at new MongoStore (/Users/biggahd/Desktop/Mars-EMS-v-1.0.0/root/backend/node_modules/connect-mongo/src/index.js:84:29)
[0]     at Hook.initialize (/Users/biggahd/Desktop/Mars-EMS-v-1.0.0/root/backend/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/session/index.js:223:39)
[0]     at Hook.wrapper [as initialize] (/Users/biggahd/Desktop/Mars-EMS-v-1.0.0/root/backend/node_modules/@sailshq/lodash/lib/index.js:3250:19)
[0]     at /Users/biggahd/Desktop/Mars-EMS-v-1.0.0/root/backend/node_modules/sails/lib/hooks/index.js:88:16
[0]     at /Users/biggahd/Desktop/Mars-EMS-v-1.0.0/root/backend/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
[0]     at /Users/biggahd/Desktop/Mars-EMS-v-1.0.0/root/backend/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:548:17
[0]     at /Users/biggahd/Desktop/Mars-EMS-v-1.0.0/root/backend/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:542:17
[0]     at _arrayEach (/Users/biggahd/Desktop/Mars-EMS-v-1.0.0/root/backend/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:85:13)
[0]     at Immediate.taskComplete [as _onImmediate] (/Users/biggahd/Desktop/Mars-EMS-v-1.0.0/root/backend/node_modules/sails/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:541:13)
[0]     at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:464:21)
[0] 
[0] 
[0] error: A hook (`orm`) failed to load!
```

I tried to run my Sails.js app, but I'm unable to connect it to cloud MongoDB.